# How can i scan a QR code in two diferents ways?

Tags: qr-code

I must update a software that uses barcodes to identify products. The company will change the barcode to a QR code. They sent me a QR code example to test and when i read it on my cell phone what I get is a URL address and not an alphanumeric string in which I find certain information depending on the position. I asked the company and they responded that the data delivered by the 2D scanner depends on a configuration in the scanner.

It can be that? Is it possible for the same code to deliver different information depending on the scanner configuration?

Information I get with the current barcode:
P50504089018575188040

Information I get with the future QR code:
https://subdomail.domain.com/scan/delivery/726267333
So in this text i can't get the same information of the current barcode.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: The QR code is what it is, and can only be read according to [official standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/62021.html) (Paywall).  But a scanner may *interpret* the read data as it is configured for. Example: data `P123` could be returned to you as `https://my.url/index.html?123`. Some scanners may run javascript scriptlets. Try to evaluate the QR code in "raw" readers like [BCTester](https://bctester.de/en/).